# IIS Http status issues

Tags: iis

The iis server in production is behaving differently from my pc for my restful api project. There are two below issues.

1) if the endpoint doesn’t exist under the website (eg https://xxx/website/invalidapi/), production iis is returning http status 404 instead of local pc is returning 500.

Below is error msg.

```
     *<div class="content-container">
        <h3>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h3>
        <h4>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <fieldset>
            <h4>Most likely causes:</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.</li>
                <li>The URL contains a typographical error.</li>
                <li>A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.</li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </div>*
```

If the website/application doesn’t exist (eg, https://xxx/invalidwebsite/api/), production iis is returning http status 500 instead of local pc returning 404.

Below is 500 error msg

```
*<div id="header">
    <h1>Server Error</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="content-container">
        <fieldset>
            <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
            <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>*
```

Is there some configuration in production iis to behave that way?

2) I am implementing iis rewrite rule to my website, the rule is to redirect the request with invalid (non-existing website) to default another website.

It is working well in my local pc. But in production iis, it is not redirecting and returning http status 403 for invalid website. If I tested to a test (existing site), it can rewrite correctly.

Is it due to the same reason as above? Kindly advise how I can fix ? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't reveal the actual error page and the substatus code from IIS logs, there isn't much to discuss.

Comment: Could you please post the details error message about the 500 error? I have run a test demo on my side. If I access the web application which is not exists. It will return Could not get any response without any status codes.

Comment: i have updated the actual error msg on my post. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Could you please share the details config about your url rewrite? According to your details error message, we still couldn't find out the details error message. I suggest you could try to open the event viewer and check the application tab and security tab to see if there is anything useful information in it.